# load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, authentication, import

I'm searching to the net but i cannot find any solution. I'm just making a simple LOG IN in android that getting the user data in MYSQL. And This error show to my log cat

load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found

can anyone help me thanks

this is my java file

```
public class DisplayloginActivity extends Activity {

Button btnlogin;
EditText etusername, etpassword;
TextView tvforgot,tv;

HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog pDialog = null;
SessionManager session;
public static final String MyPREF = "MyPrefs";
public static final String usernamepref = "usernamekey";
public static final String passwordpref = "passwordkey";
public static final String attenderno1 = "";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

//url
private static String url_login = "http://192.168.0.102/SchoolServiceTracker/Android/Connection/a.php";
private static String url_getuser = "http://192.168.106/SchoolServiceTracker/Android/Attender/getuser.php";
//JSON node name
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
static int success = 0;
//JSONParser
JSONParser sstParser = new JSONParser();
//String declaration
String attenderno, aname, licenseno, emailadd, plateno, authorizedroute, alatitude, alongitude, schoolname;


String getSuccessResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaylogin);

    //session manager
    //session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    //declare var
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameet);
    etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordet);
    tvforgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgot);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    //forgot username/password onclick
    tvforgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            forgotAlert();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Contact you School Administrator", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //login button onclick
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DisplayloginActivity.this, "", "Validating user...", true);
                //new Thread(new Runnable(){
                //  public void run() {
                //      loginattender();
                //  }
                //}).start();
                new loginattender().execute();
        }
    });
}

class loginattender extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayloginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in....");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String username = etusername.getText().toString();
        String password = etpassword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        JSONObject json = sstParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "GET", param);

        Log.d("USER: ", json.toString());

        success = 0;

        try{
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                json = sstParser.makeHttpRequest(url_getuser, "GET", params);

                Log.d("user details", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mainpage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }else if(success == 0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayloginActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("success", 0);
                i.putExtra("username", etusername.getText().toString());
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;            
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*void loginattender() {

    try{
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpPost("http//192.168.1.101/SchoolServiceTracker/Android/Connection/a.php");

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", etusername.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", etusername.getText().toString().trim()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response: " + response);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Responce from PHP : " + response);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable () {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayloginActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //String username = etusername.getText().toString();
                    //String password = etpassword.getText().toString();
                    //session.createLoginSession(username, password);
                }
            });
            DisplayloginActivity.this.finish();
            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            String usernamelite = etusername.getText().toString();
            String passwordlite = etpassword.getText().toString();
            editor.putString(usernamepref, usernamelite);
            editor.putString(passwordpref, passwordlite);
            editor.commit();
            Intent loginintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mainpage.class);

            startActivity(loginintent);
        } else {
            showAlert();
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}*/

public void forgotAlert(){
    DisplayloginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayloginActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Forgot Username/Passwrod");
            builder.setMessage("Please Contact you School Administrator")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}

public void showAlert(){
    DisplayloginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayloginActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Login Error");
            builder.setMessage("User cannot Found")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREF, 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedpreferences.contains(usernamepref));
    {
        if(sharedpreferences.contains(passwordpref)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Mainpage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.displaylogin, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: do you have a libmaliinstr.so in your libs folder?Can you tell me which methods are using that library ?

Comment: Same here with a CoolPad 8297W device. App instantly dead on start.

Comment: hi have you find the solution? I got the same error

Answer (score -1):

Just use try catch block

```
try {
    // Write your code here
}catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Error e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```